# Error when installing Xuggle to linux

Tags: linux, xuggle

I am repeatedly getting this error when trying to install Xuggle(http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads/) to linux server .

-------------------- ERROR -----------------------
Failed to install xuggle-xuggler.
You may need to be root to install to /usr/local/xuggler.
-------------------- ERROR -----------------------

I am not a root user, but I have sudo rights. Aren't sudo rights sufficient to install xuggle?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
sudo -i
```

you will be in root mode and then try to  install  xuggle-xuggler

Comment: Hi sushanth, Thanx for the reply. But even with that im getting the same error :( . any other suggestions ?

Comment: which flavor of linux you are using ?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. I am using debian linux. Anyway the problem was due to a corrupted xuggler file. I downloaded it again and tried. then it worked.